Prime number theorem in arithematic progressions, $\varphi(x, \chi)$.
Question
I am learning prime number theorem in arithematic progressions, rencently. See the following picture, which I write by myself, so maybe there is a little error.
My question is, what is the error term of $\varphi(x, \chi)$, precisely?
The proof is clear to use Perron's formula. But I don't know what $R(x,T)$is.
Could anyone help me?enter image description here
Perron's formula
Let $x \geq 4$, and $\|x\|$ denote the distance between $x$ and the nearest integer $N$. Then, for $b>\sigma_a, T \geq 2$ and $2 \leq H<(1-\theta) x$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n \leq x} a_n= & \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{b-i T}^{b+i T} f(s) \frac{x^s}{s} d s+O\left(\frac{x A_H(x) \log (x / H)}{T}\right) \\
& +O\left(\frac{x^b H B(b)}{T}\right)+O\left\{\left|a_N\right| \min \left(1, \frac{x}{T\|x\|}\right)\right\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
A_H(x) \geq \max _{x-x / H<n \leq x+x / H}\left|a_n\right|.
\end{equation*}
Sketch (From Lecture)
By Perron's formula, we have
\begin{equation*}
\psi(x, \chi)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{b-i T_1}^{b+i T_1}\left\{-\frac{L^{\prime}(s, \chi)}{L(s, \chi)}\right\} \frac{x^s}{s} d s+O\left(R_1\left(x, T_1\right)\right),
\end{equation*}
where $b=1+\frac{1}{\log x}, T \leq T_1 \leq T+1$ such that $\left|T_1-\Im \rho\right|>\frac{1}{c \log T}$ for all non-trivial zeros $\rho$, and
\begin{equation*}
R_1\left(x, T_1\right)=\log x \min \left\{1, \frac{x}{T_1\|x\|}\right\}+\frac{x \log ^2(k x T)}{T_1} .
\end{equation*}
I can't compute the term
$$
\frac{x \log ^2(k x T)}{T_1}.
$$
Thanks for everyone.

What do you mean, “compute” that term?—it's already in closed form. You can use $$1/T_1 \ll 1/T$$ if that's helpful.
